# How do I include this file with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have this file `certify.command` but I have no idea how to include it in `pyinstaller -Fw --icon=AppIcon.icns Converter.py`.

I want my app to run on my other macs and to use my app I need to run the `Install Certificates.command` file so my app can access HTTPS. I don't want to install python on my other macs to run that file. That is why I want to include the file in my app so it can run the file on startup.

The `Install Certificates.command` is located in the python3.9 folder which requires the installation of python.

Can someone pls help?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)? The `--add-data` method can help you do that.

Comment: Oh... seems simple... I will go re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the documentation... My bad for not reading it. All I had to do was add `--add-data` with the file name afterwards; `"certify.command:."`